# FabricJS scale image to fit width / size

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How do i scale image to fit the container size correctly? I want a grid of two images and each image to fit the provided size.

https://codepen.io/peteringram0/pen/gebYWo?editors=0010

```
img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 300
    // Scale image to fit width / height ?
 });
```

EDIT: Sorry i didn't explain my question very clearly. Im looking to position it within the grid but as a 'cover' type. https://codepen.io/peteringram0/pen/xWwZmy?editors=0011. E.g. in the link there are 4 images in a grid but the images are in the centre and are overflowing. I want to get each of the images vertically centred with no overflow outside the set size. Thanks (x should be in the centre, while keeping the aspect ratio)

Comment: If you were looking to have responsive objects within objects, I just solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719714/centering-and-scaling-canvas-object-inside-another-canvas-object-by-width-height/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to scale image object to given width or height, use [scaleToWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToWidth) and [scaleToHeight](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToHeight) respectively.

I've removed the height and width specified inside img.set function from your code. And added a scaeToHeight and scaleToWidth method.
Use the code as below.

```
window.fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, (img) => {
  img.set({
    left: 300,
    top: 0
  });
  img.scaleToHeight(300);
  img.scaleToWidth(300);
  canvas.add(img);
})
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hazeebp/195uan6f/1/

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have edited my post above. Sorry i did not make this more clear when posting before.

Comment: let scale = Math.min(300 / img.width, 300 / img.height)
      img.scale(scale)
      canvas.add(img)
But! This works OK if the angle is 0.