# Centering and scaling canvas object inside another canvas object by width/height in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Goal:** To center an object (horizontally and vertically) inside another object (rectangle or group) on `canvas` via `Fabric.js` or via Javascript which keeps the original object aspect ratio the same, but also not exceed the parent object width/height proportions?

The parent object (rectangle or group) won't be centered on the `canvas` element.

Here's the code I have so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my8hky

My `app.component.ts` so far:

```
canvas: fabric.Canvas;

ngOnInit() {
  this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#eee'
  });
  this.canvas.add(rect);

  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png', (img) => {
    let bounds = rect.getBoundingRect();
    let oImg = img.set({
      left: bounds.left,
      top: bounds.top,
      width: rect.width
    }).scale(1);
    this.canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
  });
}
```

Not only is the new object not centered vertically, but also not centered horizontally if the rectangle object height is decreased (for example to `50px` in height).

I realize I'm only declaring the inner image object width to be the same as the parent rectangle boundary width.

**Current solution:**

Parent rectangle `width: 300` and `height: 200`:

[image: 300px x 200px - Undesired Fabric.js centering solution]

Parent rectangle `width: 300` and `height: 50`:

[image: 300px x 50px - Undesired Fabric.js centering solution]

**Desired solution:**

Parent rectangle `width: 300` and `height: 200`:

[image: 300px x 200px - Desired Fabric.js centering solution]

Parent rectangle `width: 300` and `height: 50`:

[image: 300px x 50px - Desired Fabric.js centering solution]

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.. Here's the StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg4fis

The trick was to first add the rectangle to a `Fabric` group, like so:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  width: 450,
  height: 200,
  fill: '#e3e3e3',
});

var rectGroup = new fabric.Group([rect], {
  name: 'Rectangle',
});

this.canvas.add(rectGroup);
```

Then, I was able to establish the parent (group) element boundaries and use a variable scaling factor to set the image via `Math` functionality:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png', (img) => {
  let bounds = rectGroup.getBoundingRect();

  const scaleFactor = Math.min(
    Math.min(1, bounds.width / img.width),
    Math.min(1, bounds.height / img.height)
  );
  img.scale(scaleFactor);

  img.set({
    top: bounds.top + Math.max(bounds.height - img.height * scaleFactor, 0)/2,
    left: bounds.left + Math.max(bounds.width - img.width * scaleFactor, 0)/2,
  });

  rectGroup.addWithUpdate(img);
  this.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: You can do [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwab3d) as well, add image object on the center of rectangle object,

Comment: @Durga Thank you, this is a great solution for if you want the proportions to be kept for the image and not resized. I changed the height on the rectangle to something like `50px` and the image was leaking out of the box.

Comment: did change for position, you can take your code for scale

Comment: @Durga - any chance you could help me with a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826290/fabricjs-how-to-auto-resize-image-to-fit-group-or-rectangle-object