# FabricJS: How to auto-resize image to fit group or rectangle object?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Goal:** I'm seeking to add an image to a FabricJS group or rectangle object, and for the image to maintain it's original aspect ratio and center fit it's parent width/height.

I don't want the image overflow to show, but will show the overflow as a less opaque green in the examples below:

---

**Landscape Image Example**:

If it was a landscape oriented image, it would scale to max height, but then center itself with regards to width placement:

[image: Image resized within fabricjs rectangle - landscape orientation]

Since I'm not looking for the image overflow to show, the final product should look like this:

[image: Image resized within fabricjs rectangle final look - landscape orientation]

---

**Portrait Image Example**:

Similarly, if the image was portrait oriented, the image would scale 100% in width, but center itself in height:

[image: Image resized within fabricjs rectangle - portrait orientation]

And then negating the overflow, this is what I'm looking for as a final product:

[image: Image resized within fabricjs rectangle final product - portrait orientation]

---

Here's my stackblitz so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpfkkw

With the base-case code as follows:

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#e3e3e3',
});

var rectGroup = new fabric.Group([rect], {
    name: 'Rectangle',
});

this.canvas.add(rectGroup);

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://placehold.it/888x500&text=16:9', (img) => {
    let bounds = rectGroup.getBoundingRect();

    const scaleFactor = Math.min(
        Math.min(bounds.width / img.width),
        Math.min(bounds.height / img.height)
    );
    img.scale(scaleFactor);

    img.set({
        top: bounds.top + Math.max(bounds.height - img.height * scaleFactor, 0)/2,
        left: bounds.left + Math.max(bounds.width - img.width * scaleFactor, 0)/2,
    });

    rectGroup.addWithUpdate(img);
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}
```

This is obviously not the right solution, but a start. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, here's the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yoo8h5

First, I compared whether or not the rectangle aspect ratio is proportional to the image through an `if/else` statement which decides whether or not to initially scale the image to the rectangle width/height.

Then I set either the top or the left attribute of the image to the rectangle boundary point. Then calculating the center point of the rectangle and subtracting half of the image's boundary and lastly, setting the rectangle group object's `clipPath` to that of the rectangle, it worked!

---

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://placehold.it/888x500&text=16:9', (img) => {
    let bounds = rectGroup.getBoundingRect();

    if ((bounds.height / bounds.width) >= (img.height / img.width)) {
        img.scaleToHeight(bounds.height);
        img.set({
            top: bounds.top,
            left: (bounds.left + (bounds.width/2)) - (img.getBoundingRect().width/2)
        });
    }
    else {
        img.scaleToWidth(bounds.width);
        img.set({
            top: (bounds.top + (bounds.height/2)) - (img.getBoundingRect().height/2),
            left: bounds.left
        });
    }

    rectGroup.addWithUpdate(img);
    rectGroup.clipPath = rect;
    this.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here but chipping in in case this might be helpful.

You were heading in the right direction with `Math.min`, but you can use `Math.max` instead for the side with the larger group/image ratio to scale to the full length of the side. You can then set the x y origins to `center`.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://placehold.it/888x500&text=16:9', (img) => {
    let bounds = rectGroup.getBoundingRect();

    const scaleFactor = Math.max(bounds.width / img.width, bounds.height / img.height);

    img.set({
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      scaleX: scaleFactor,
      scaleY: scaleFactor
    });

    rectGroup.addWithUpdate(img);
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}
```